# How do we get the SmtpServer NetworkCredentials while using a mail service in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, smtpclient

I am implementing a simple `Forgot password`, feature in my Xamarin Forms app. When the player provides an `email` in the text field, will check if the email exists in the database, if yes, will get the password associated with that email and send the password to that email.

In the following smtp step `SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("email", "password");`from where do we get the credentials to provide in `Network credentials` as email / password ?

```
namespace soccerapp
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class ForgotPassword : ContentPage
    {
        private SQLiteConnection conn;
        string emailText;

        public ForgotPassword()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            conn = DependencyService.Get<Isqlite>().GetConnection();
        }

        public void btnSend_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            emailText = txtEmail.Text;

            int count = (from x in conn.Table<PlayerDetails>().Where(x => x.Email == emailText) select x).Count();

            if (count != 0)
            {
                var detail = conn.Table<PlayerDetails>().First(x => x.Email == emailText);
                var playerPassword = detail.Password;
                try
                {

                    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                    SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

                    mail.From = new MailAddress("admin@somesite.nz");
                    mail.To.Add(emailText);
                    mail.Subject = "Hello";
                    mail.Body = "Your soccer password: "+playerPassword;

                    SmtpServer.Port = 587;
                    SmtpServer.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                    SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;
                    SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                    SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("some_email@gmail.com", "password");

                    SmtpServer.Send(mail);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    DisplayAlert("Faild", ex.Message, "OK");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Quick question, do you have your own email server and domain to use or are you looking to use an external email service such as sendgrid?

Comment: Yes, I have my domain and own email server

Comment: Alright perfect, I would make an email account on the domain for sending these emails out, typically something like "password-reset@yourDomainName".

Once you've made the account just place the email and password for that account in the placeholders above and see if a test email will work.

If i can point out a few things however, maybe consider storing the email credentials in a secure file instead of in code. And further to the architecture of the solution, it would definitely be more secure to generate a "reset password" page instead of storing and sending plaintext passwords to users